# how to .get() all entry box insert into sqlite 3 in python tkinter

Tags: python, sqlite, tkinter

how to .get() all entry box insert into sqlite 3 in python tkinter

I have Create loop entry boxes

I have try all entry boxes .get() and insert into sqlite 3

but insert only last three entry boxes only

I have insert all boxes into sqlite 3

all entry boxes insert into sqlite 3 in single row

```
import sqlite3

#------------------------------------
class sample:
    def __init__(self, root):
        self.root = root


        self.all_entries = []

        showButton = Button(root, text='Show all text', command=self.showEntries)
        showButton.pack()

        addboxButton = Button(root, text='<Add Time Input>', fg="Red", command=self.addBox)
        addboxButton.pack()


        savee = Button(root, text='Save', fg="green", command=self.save)
        savee.pack()

    def save(self):

        print(self.all_entries)
        con = sqlite3.connect(database=r'data.db')
        cur = con.cursor()

        cur.execute("Insert into e_transations (sl,id,datee) values(?,?,?)", (
            self.ent1.get(), self.ent2.get(), self.ent3.get()
        ))
        con.commit()

    def addBox(self):

        frame = Frame(root)
        frame.pack()

        Label(frame, text='From').grid(row=0, column=0)

        self.ent1 = Entry(frame)
        self.ent1.grid(row=1, column=0)

        Label(frame, text='To').grid(row=0, column=1)

        self.ent2 = Entry(frame)
        self.ent2.grid(row=1, column=1)

        self.ent3 = Entry(frame)
        self.ent3.grid(row=1, column=2)

        self.all_entries.append((self.ent1, self.ent2,self.ent3))

    # ------------------------------------

    def showEntries(self):
        for number, (self.ent1,self.ent2,self.ent3) in enumerate(self.all_entries):
            print(number, self.ent1.get(), self.ent2.get(), self.ent3.get())

    # ------------------------------------


root = Tk()
obj = sample(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: `ent1`, `ent2`, and `ent3` seem to be temporary variables, why are you using instance variables for them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`save()` should save the values of all the entries in `self.all_entries`, not just the last `self.ent1`, `self.ent2`, and `self.ent3`.

```
    def save(self):

        print(self.all_entries)
        con = sqlite3.connect(database=r'data.db')
        cur = con.cursor()

        values = [[entry.get for entry in entry_set] for entry_set in self.all_entries]

        cur.executemany("Insert into e_transations (sl,id,datee) values(?,?,?)", values)
        con.commit()
```

`self.all_entries` should contain the values from `.get()` of the entry widgets, not

Comment: `self.all_entries` cannot be passed directly as the required arguments because it is a list of `Entry` widgets.  The required arguments is a list of values inside those entries instead.  Also if there are more than 3 entries in the list, e.g. 6 or 9 entries, it does not work.

Comment: I misread, I thought it was using `.get()` on the entries when it pushed into `self.all_entries`.